# I want to get multi line by using string data type not char type

Tags: c++

Look at the examples to see what do I want

```
string name
cin >> name;
```

This example does not allow spaces or multi line

```
char name[20];
cin.getline(name,20);
```

This example allow spaces and multi line

**My question:**
I want to using string data type with getline function or other function work with string  data type allows mulitline and spaces

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see a question here. Could you please explicitly state your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a global getline function that works on strings.

```
string name;
getline(cin,name);
```

You can get multiple lines by specifying a terminating character other than '\n'

```
getline(cin,name,'#');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use the char method as it is essentially buffered. But if you want to read in a single line string with spaces you can do,

```
  std::string name;
  std::getline( std::cin, name );
```